# Scaling Image with Java produces black space

Tags: java, image, scaling, bufferedimage

I have written the following function to scale down images. But while the scaling works, the produced images are always square images and have a black space at the bottom or right side of the image. What I am doing wrong here?

```
private BufferedImage scaleImageTo(BufferedImage image, int width, int height) throws Exception {
    // Fetch the width and height of the source image, ...
    int srcWidth = image.getWidth();
    int srcHeight = image.getHeight();

    // ... verify that it is larger than the target image ...
    if (srcWidth < width && srcHeight < height) {
        throw new Exception();
    }

    // ... and setup the target image with the same dimensions.
    BufferedImage scaledImage;
    if (image.getType() == BufferedImage.TYPE_CUSTOM) {
        scaledImage = new BufferedImage(width,height,BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
    } else {
        scaledImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, image.getType());
    }

    // Calculate the scale parameter.
    double scale = 1;
    if (srcWidth - width >= srcHeight - height) {
        scale = ((double) width) / srcWidth;
    } else {
        scale = ((double) height) / srcHeight;
    }

    // Setup the scaling transformation ...
    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
    at.scale(scale, scale);

    // ... and the transformation interpolation type.
    AffineTransformOp scaleOp = new AffineTransformOp(at, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);

    // Generate the scaled image  ... 
    scaledImage = scaleOp.filter(image, scaledImage);

    // ... and return it.
    return scaledImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are always using the same scaling factor for the x- and the y-direction.

Although you could fix this by specifying two scaling factors like this

```
double scaleX = (double) width / srcWidth;
double scaleY = (double) height / srcHeight;
AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
at.scale(scaleX, scaleY);
```

I wonder why you are doing is this way. Just creating a scaled version of an image is usually rather easy...:

```
private static BufferedImage scaleImageTo(
    BufferedImage image, int width, int height) 
{
    BufferedImage scaledImage =
        new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g = scaledImage.createGraphics();
    g.setRenderingHint(
        RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, 
        RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height, null);
    g.dispose();
    return scaledImage;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I am using always the same scaling factor for the x- and the y-direction, because otherwise I would scale to the given width and height without keeping the aspect ratio. If I always stretch with the same factor, I keep it. The width and height I give as parameters should just limit the size in x and y direction. It is something like a bounding box. However, I don't see the benefits of the scaling mechanism you presented. Is it just another approach or are there some benefits.

Comment: @Avedo I think primarily that it is simpler (and it may be more efficient, but that's only an assumption until now). However, you should probably explain what exactly you mean when you say that the widht/hight should just "limit" the size (possibly, add it in the original question).

Comment: The error was that I did use the width and height of the bounding box. If I calculate the size of the scaled image before I actually scale it, and use these dimensions, it works as expected. However, as you have pointed me in the right direction and your answer is obviously correct, I accept this one.